# How to add text to a plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have obtained an ordination table from mothur (from a NMDS analysis) and I want to plot it with R, showing in the plot the name of the different groups.

My data ('nmds.axes' file) is the following:

```
group      axis1     axis2
F3D0   -0.160727  0.161163
F3D1   -0.202877 -0.346617
F3D141  0.019257  0.114220
F3D142  0.109841  0.099407
F3D143  0.020320  0.205298
F3D144  0.069564  0.252836
F3D145  0.077754  0.191122
F3D146 -0.026143  0.217766
F3D147  0.093228  0.237383
F3D148  0.039519  0.222896
F3D149  0.024681  0.142421
F3D150 -0.056318  0.119949
F3D2    0.331630 -0.205620
F3D3    0.237954 -0.193381
F3D5   -0.062992 -0.199847
F3D6    0.176253 -0.148854
F3D7    0.148191 -0.171803
F3D8    0.034022 -0.321173
F3D9    0.041995 -0.291805
Mock   -0.915153 -0.085362
```

And I have done the following:

```
nmds<-read.table(file="nmds.axes", header=T)
rownames(nmds)<- nmds[,1]
nombres.nmds<-factor(rownames(nmds))
plot(nmds$axis2~nmds$axis1, xlab="Axis 1", ylab="Axis 2")
text(nmds, labels=nombres.nmds)
```

However, doing the 'text' command or not outputs the same plot, only with white dots for the 'groups' but not names on it.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to specify both the x values and the y values for the text. Presumably you want `with(nmds, text(x = axis1, y = axis2, labels = nombres.nmds))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked!!